# How to exclude a folder root and include only contents while zipping using grunt-contrib-compress

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a way by which we can exclude the folder root when you are compressing all files within a folder?

```
grunt.initConfig({
  compress: {
    main: {
      files: [
        {expand: true, src: ['dist/**', 'xyz/**']},
      ]
    }
  }   
});
```

How can we exclude dist and xyz folders from being included in the compressed file?

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your want the files under the folder included, you need to change the `cwd` for each target so that they are treated as the root for each glob pattern

```
grunt.initConfig({
  compress: {
    main: {
      files: [
        {cwd: 'dist/', expand: true, src: ['**']},
        {cwd: 'xyz/', expand: true, src: ['**']},
      ]
    }
  }   
});
```

If you are looking just exclude the folders in the root, then use `!` patterns that Kyle mentioned

Answer (score 6):

Prepending a `!` will negate a pattern:

```
{expand: true, src: ['dist/**', '!xyz/**']}
```

See: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns